# check for null before getting property in linq to sql query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, entity

I have a query that looks like this, if there is no RegisteredInstructor an error gets thrown. Is there a way to fix this or check during the linq query?

```
viewModel.SpaceEvents = yogaSpace.YogaSpaceEvents.Where(j => j.EventDateTime >= DateTime.Now).Select(j => new EventResult
                {
       RegsiteredInstructorName = j.RegisteredInstructor.Name,
       RegisteredInstructorId =   j.RegisteredInstructor.RegisteredTeacherId,
       RegisteredTeacherImage =   j.RegisteredInstructor.RegisteredTeacherImage
 }).ToList();
```

where RegisteredInstructor is a

```
public virtual Profile RegisteredInstructor { get; set; }
```

in my YogaSpaceEvents entity.

Comment: you mean when RegisteredInstructor is null?

Comment: Include RegisteredInstructor  null check also in where condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.This could fix your error, checking `j.RegisteredInstructor` is null or not.

```
viewModel.SpaceEvents = yogaSpace.YogaSpaceEvents
                               .Where(j => j.EventDateTime >= DateTime.Now)
                               .Select(j => new EventResult
                {
       RegsiteredInstructorName = j.RegisteredInstructor!= null?j.RegisteredInstructor.Name:"",
       RegisteredInstructorId =   j.RegisteredInstructor!= null?j.RegisteredInstructor.RegisteredTeacherId:0,
       RegisteredTeacherImage =   j.RegisteredInstructor!= null?j.RegisteredInstructor.RegisteredTeacherImage:""
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: ternary operator! that's what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: Or even shorter: RegsiteredInstructorName = j.RegisteredInstructor ?? "";

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator